# making changes to wordpress site using http requests

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, http

As the title says, is it possible for example to install a theme, add a text widget, change a picture remotely with an HTTP request (or some other method)? I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could. However, that can be a dangerous practice, because it allows anyone to mess with your website.

The way that first comes to mind is something like: create /edit_site.php and communicate your intent via a POST to it. Then, edit_site.php will run some server side script that will do what you want. (Of course, you'll have to write the server side script)